# How do assign a variable value in a function? unix korn shell

Tags: function, shell, variables, unix, return-value

I want to assign a value to a variable (it will be different variables) but I want to use a function to do that, it would be something like "Pass argument by value" as C# do that.

Here is the example what I want to do:

```
#/bin/ksh
MyVariable=""

ValidateVariableValue()
{
   ${1}="Working with this!"
}

ValidateVariableValue "MyVariable"

echo "value is: ${MyVariable}"
```

I want that my function receive the name of the variable and assign a value inside of my function.

That is possible? there's any way to do something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to like this :

```
#/bin/ksh
MyVariable=""

function ValidateVariableValue()
{
    eval $1="Working with this!"
}

ValidateVariableValue MyVariable

echo "value is: ${MyVariable}"
```

Comment: I copied the same code as you, is not working...
`syntax error: `(' unexpected`

Comment: I had to remove the () on the function but I'm having issues
It work if I do this `eval $1="working"` but not if I do this `eval $1="Working with this"` it's displaying that "with" is not found

Comment: I must admit I didn't test with ksh but with bash and zsh it works so what if you escape space character like this $1="Working\ with\ this" ?

Comment: Yes, is working, you have to escape the space.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that !